# How to separate the logic in the implementation of a method whose signature is in two interfaces implemented by the class?

Tags: java, interface

Question from interview:

How can I separate logic in method `getString()` of class `ImplementationAB` depending on the type of interface to which an instance of this class is assigned?

`instanceof` is not suitable for this task, it determines whether a class implements an interface:

```
interface A {
    public String getString();
}

interface B {
    public String getString();
}

class ImplementationAB implements A, B {
    
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        //TODO
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new ImplementationAB();
        B b = new ImplementationAB();
       
        System.out.println(a instanceof B); //true
        System.out.println(b instanceof A); //true
        a.getString();
        b.getString();              
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t. Use two different implementation classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. At runtime, the information about which interface you used to instantiate the class is no longer available. Add the following lines to your code:

```
System.out.println(a.getClass()); // ImplementationAB
System.out.println(b.getClass()); // ImplementationAB
```

Here you can see that only information about the interfaces is available, but only about the class.